# Empty area in tags block on user profile page

Tags: bug, tags, design, profile-page

In [my profile](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/339911/%CE%B1%CE%BB%CE%B5%CF%87%CE%BF%CE%BB%CF%85%CF%84?tab=topactivity) there's an empty area in the Tags block:

> [image]

Each tag on that block occupies 66px in height. The last tag here is [bug](/questions/tagged/bug), and this tag occupies 144px height, so it easily can contain at least two tags. Why do we see that empty area here?

Comment: I think it's because you always have the graph on the right with the 4 recent posts with activity. The top post actually has 3 lines of title, so it takes up more space. If you look at my [profile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5515060/lino?tab=topactivity) for example, you see less of a margin.

Comment: @Lino then the solution could rely on some specific maximum height (in px) or to fill as much as possible items for the paired block to align both of them.

Comment: @Lino is correct. [Here is how it looks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6poNw.png) when titles are being trimmed.

Comment: @Shadow fine. Should it be fixed or leave it as is?

Comment: I don't think it's a bug, but valid as a minor feature request. It would make the site look better, but really can't see it ever being done.

Comment: @Shadow well, will u consider this as bug when the number of tags in the block became 4? 3? 2? 1? Only 0? In other words how many empty pixels allowed there?